# Replacements for GetMacOSStatusErrorString/GetMacOSStatusCommentString

Tags: macos, cocoa

The functions GetMacOSStatusErrorString and GetMacOSStatusCommentString appear to have been deprecated as of 10.8. Are there any non-deprecated replacement functions for these handy debugging functions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `[NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:errorCode userInfo:nil]` to get an `NSError` representing the `OSStatus` of `errorCode`. `NSError` provides the ability to get a localized error message from the error code (`-localizedDescription`), or a regular unlocalized one for debugging purposes (`-description`).

Comment: That's missing some (possibly a lot of) error codes, though. For example, `ioErr`'s comment is the not-entirely-user-friendly-but-at-least-descriptive “I/O error (bummers)”, whereas NSError simply gives the generic “The operation couldn't be completed”, which is the same description it gives for most other OSStatuses.

Comment: `NSError` is the intended replacement so it's unfortunate that it doesn't provide reasonable output for some error codes. It seems worthy of a bug report to Apple.

Comment: Thanks. It seems more hassle to go through for a simple NSLog debug output and as Peter points out it does leave a lot of errors out, but it's good to know the replacement